# Add title and subtitle to Chromecast loading screen with cwac-mediarouter?

Tags: android, chromecast, commonsware-cwac

I am working android chromecast app and since I want to have default actionbar rather than using android support v7 actionbar I used [cwac-mediarouter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-mediarouter).

The problem I'm facing right now is I was unable to add a title and subtitle to the Chromecast default loading screen. When I trying with mediarouter-v7 I was able to add title using MediaMetadata and MediaInfo classes.

```
    MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, getString(R.string.loading));
    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ALBUM_TITLE, getString(R.string.app_name));

    MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(getString(R.string.video_url))
            .setContentType(getString(R.string.content_type_mp4))
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
            .build();
    try {
        mRemoteMediaPlayer.load(mApiClient, mediaInfo, true)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {
                        if (mediaChannelResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            mVideoIsLoaded = true;
                            //TODO Pause Video on Device
                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(getPackageName(), "startVideo Ex : " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I have tried add bundle data to RemotePlaybackClient play method in both Bundle type params but failed. 
Can someone help me on adding a title to my chromecast loading screen?

Comment: `MediaInfo` and `MediaMetadata` are both from the Cast SDK, not from `mediarouter-v7`. I have no idea how they would be used with `RemotePlaybackClient`, or if that is actually possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare I used Please MediaInfo and MediaMetadata with mediarouter-v7 not with cwac-mediarouter. Please check the updated question on how I used it with mediarouter-v7.